# how can i read firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here's my code, it is the exact copy of the docs but it says that ref.on is not a function. maybe i forgot to put a module in the import but i couldn't find any information about that.

```
function readpixels() {
  const db = getDatabase();
  const ref = ref(db, 'pixels');
  ref.on('value', (pixel) => {
    console.log("read")
  })
}
```

and here are the import lines:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, push, set } from "firebase/database";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the new v9 functions, but in your code you are then trying to use the older syntax. You'll have to pick one or the other.

In v9 syntax, the `ref.on("value"` would be:

```
import { onValue } from "firebase/database";
...
onValue(ref, (pixel) => {
  console.log("read")
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading from the Realtime Database with the v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_2).